# How to deploy django with uWsgi and nginx on CentOS

Tags: deployment, django, uwsgi

My version of Django is 1.6.3

I downloaded uwsgi-2.0.4. Someone says installing uwsgi with command make while someone use python setup.py build. What exactly is the difference?

I saw a tutorial that says create a python file named django_wsgi.py, but I already have a wsgi.py in my django project. It confuses me a lot.  Django_wsgi, uWsgi, wsgi....
What's the difference and function?

Then I want to test if uwsgi is working normally, so I wrote a test.py:

```
# test.py
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return "Hello World"
```

I execute it with

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

but it fails with the error

```
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--http:8001'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Its very old thread but I also faced the same issue and found a solution for my case so just wanted to update here in case someone else looking for the same: **First** its not uwsgi --http :8001  its uwsgi --socket :8001 **Second** You should run this command from your django project working dir. and it works configure nginx settings for django and restart nginx and run the django app .